# May custom fields be used for CartThrob email notification To and From fields?

Tags: cartthrob, email, notification

I've tried this a couple of different ways with no success.  I can hardcode the "to" line for the customer email notification and it works fine. But if i try to use a variable - like the customer's user-entered email address - no notification is received.  In CartTrhib's order settings, I have the "Customer Email" field mapped to my custom field in my orders channel.  It's being captured and shows correctly within the email notification itself.  But I don't seem to be able to use it in the "to" field for the email notification's settings.  Are custom fields - even a mapped one like customer email - not available to use?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have discovered the answer with my trial and error.  What's not clear in the docs is that the variable {customer_email} is in fact a global variable that gets its content from the mapping of the Customer Email field, no matter what the custom field is called in your orders channel.

Comment: It's in the docs though. http://cartthrob.com/docs/backend/notifications/index.html "Use these variables in the from name, from email, to email fields as needed."

Comment: Yeah but i found "(use a [variable][#variables] if needed)" to be misleading a bit.  In my mind explicitly precluding the use of custom fields is worth mentioning. My client would also like to be able to take a custom field and add it to the subject line so that looking at their emails, they don't all look the same - but that's not supported.

Comment: [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster) might be useful to you.

Comment: I'll certainly be using it for future projects.  This one has exceedingly modest needs for notifications.  I just couldn't figure out why, at first, custom field names weren't working. Now I know!

Comment: Jean did you ever figure this out?  I am trying to add a custom member field to the subject line of an order notification.  A Quote Request Has Been Made {customer_preferred_location} -- my custom member field is preferred_location

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide some additional information on another way to solve this problem (for those who aren't familiar).

Postmaster v1.2 provides CartThrob integration support out of the box, and the next version (1.3) will bring things like Abandoned Cart Notifications for which CartThrob now charges $500.

Postmaster is definitely a premium solution and at face value can seem like more than one might need. But the template tags and options for CT are much more complete than what they even provide. I designed Postmaster to make scenarios just like this a breeze to fix. It takes just a few minutes to advanced templating with CT setup with any email service you desire.

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/read/postmaster-v1.2